# Crashing when trying to pull image from URL with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am saving the image url successfully from an api and am having issues showing it when I run the app. avatarString has the correct url but as soon as I get to the next line I keep getting:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My avatarData var is returning as nil. I don't know what why. Running Xcode Beta 6.3. Thanks for any help.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

        var avatarString = NSURL(string: self.userInfo.avatarURL)!


        var avatarData = NSData(contentsOfURL: avatarString, options: nil, error: nil)

        var avatarImage = UIImage(data: avatarData!)

        self.avatarImage.image = avatarImage

    })
```

Comment: is the avatorurl nil? is there really data at the url?

Comment: you have network? try passing an error and looking at the error

Comment: By the way you should always check if you force the unwrapping of an optional is successful, in your case: if var avatarString = NSURL(string: self.userInfo.avatarURL)! { ...}

Comment: @Daij-Djan I get Printing description of error:
0x0000000000000000

Comment: Also you are updating UI from background thread. You need to perform this line self.avatarImage.image = avatarImage on the main thread.  So use this code instead: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() , ^{
        self.avatarImage.image = avatarImage
    });

Comment: printf the intermediate values: `self.userInfo`, `self.userInfo.avatarURL`, `avatarString`, `avatarImage`, just before return. See where the nil value occurs. Or you can place a breakpoint and then single-step through in the debugger examining the values as you go. Never force-unwrap "!" any value that could ever, under any circumstances be nil else you can crash--oh wait, it did crash. Never ignore the error return unless you are 100% sure that an error can never under any circumstances occur.

Comment: @Daij-Djan @Zaph Sorry. Messed up the pass through. I am getting this error now `Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x7fee0a0bcb40 {NSURL=www.photoshelter.com/img-get/U000084E4417qzzI})`

Comment: Should that URL be "http://www.photoshelter.com/img-get/U000084E4417qzzI"?

Answer (score 2):

[image]Always do UI related work(setting ImageView image etc) in Main queue
And heavy works like downloading data ,do off the main queue, try like this:

```
 if let avatarString = NSURL(string: self.userInfo.avatarURL) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)){

                let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: avatarString)
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    if imageData != nil {
                        self.avatarImage?.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

May be it helps.