# IOS 8 progress bar delay to update while downloading (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I did create an app which the user can download some assets.
I am using the NSURLSession to download and track the progress with the UIProgressView.

Folow my code:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    var progress = ("\(((totalBytesWritten * 100) / totalBytesExpectedToWrite))" as NSString).floatValue / 100

    println("progress: \(progress)")

    progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
    progressLabel.text = "\(progresso)"     
}
```

With this code I can see in the console the values from 0.0 to 1.0
But my progress bar view only updates at 0.0, 0.4, 0.9 , 1.0. Or some thing like that.

Comment: You need to download off the main thread.

Comment: I do not know how to do that Do you have some sample(could be swift or objective c). Thanks

Comment: See this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28952815/451475)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer with the help of Zaph.

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    var progress = ("\(((totalBytesWritten * 100) / totalBytesExpectedToWrite))" as NSString).floatValue / 100

    println("progress: \(progress)")

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)    

    }

}
```